# EPiServer Development

Tags: api, sdk, episerver

Aside from Episerver.com

What other websites do people who develop using EPiServer use as development resources!? Been using coderesort.com but I find that it lacks examples of how to do stuff.

Many thanks,

J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding missing examples on CodeResort, did you register and log in? It is running on Trac, which means all modules (committed to the hosted Subversion repository) is available with full source code, directly browsable. There is lots of code in there!

See https://www.coderesort.com/p/epicode/browser

/Steve

Comment: Thanks Steve, I had missed that! It looks quite comprehensive once you can browse the source code. Many Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The general resources I use for EPiServer development:

1. [EPiServer World](http://world.episerver.com/): official developer community website. Includes blogs and official docs.
2. [Joel Abrahamsson blog](http://joelabrahamsson.com/episerver/): the most popular EPi-dev in EPiServer community.
3. [Ted Gustaf blog](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/): another well-known guy in the community.
4. [Epinova blog](http://www.epinova.no/blog/tags/episerver/): the blog of big EPiServer partner.
5. [Mathias Kunto blog](https://blog.mathiaskunto.com/): yet another EPiServer dev blog.
6. [Fredrik Haglund's blog](http://blog.fredrikhaglund.se/): popular EPiServer dev blog (but outdated).

Answer (score 3):

another good place is http://labs.episerver.com/ which aggregates most of EPiServer blogs in one place.

Answer (score 3):

You can find over 150+ EpiServer tutorials here: [JonDJones Blog](http://jondjones.com/blog/episerver/)

I also have a lot of EpiServer code on my github including several sample sites: [JonDJones Github](https://github.com/jondjones?tab=repositories)

Answer (score 2):

If you've not seen [EPiServer World](http://world.episerver.com/) then it's a great place to check out - especially the blogs on there. 
Most EPiServer things are generally found on EPiServer developers blogs such as this one <s>[EPiGirl](http://epinz.blogspot.com/)</s> (now deleted but there *are* others).

Hope this helps,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

You always try the "secret" customized google search, that searches episerver blogs, forums and sdks at http://labs.episerver.com/google

Answer (score 1):

Oh, forgot, we also have an IRC channel that is fairly active.

More information on my blog on EPiServer Labs:

http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Steve-Celius/Dates/112266/6/Join-us-on-IRC/

Comment: This link seems not to work. The site exists but produces an error.

Answer (score 1):

There is also http://epiwiki.se/ but I don't know of any public EPi resource that a Google Search won't find. Google will also get you good results from the EPi World Forum.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked quite a bit at the source code for the edit/admin interface, its been very helpful.
Browsing through the libraries in your favorite decompiler or the object explorer in visual studio.