# What are the steps to creating a new EPiServer Project

Tags: episerver

How do you go about setting up a new EPiServer website? I can't seem to get from an empty visual studio project to a deployed website without having to fix all kinds of file path and referencing issues.

If you have a smooth process for creating an EPiServer site from scratch and deploying it to a web server... I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Some more hints: http://world.episerver.com/Get-Started/EPiServer-CMS/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126102/episerver-development

Comment: Nowadays you just create a new ASP.NET (MVC) project and add packages from the EPiServer NuGet feed: http://nuget.episerver.com/feed/packages.svc/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I started out with EPiServer, I found [this blog series](http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/12/part-1-setting-up-the-development-environment-create-an-episerver-site-from-scratch/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+frederikvig+%28Frederik+Vig+-+ASP.NET+developer%29&utm_content=Google+Reader) to be extremely helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

Setup a framework site that you fix, maintain and add general stuff too. Then copy that every time you start a new project. In my experience that's the smoothest way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do you create a new site? Do you use the EPiServer deployment centre or the Visual Studio template? And how you deal with the fact that EpiServer is using files in your program Files directory... especially when it comes to committing to source control or publishing the website?

Comment: I use the Deployment Center. You can just move out the Program Files folders and put in your project dir (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333612/setting-up-a-new-episerver-6-project-with-source-control/2334123), this probably isn't the best idea though (unless you plan to hack some files in those dirs and want the hacks source controlled), better to have the version of the product installed in all environments used.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use the Visual Studio Integration for EPiServer. Create a new EPiServer project and starts coding. When the skeleton is ready to go I move the database to a central server, update the connection strings, move the VPP folder to a shared server and update the paths in web.config to it. Then it's time to put the code in source control and a project is started.

When time comes for initial deployment to test / production I copy the database and VPP to the server and use Visual Studio's deploy mechanism to compile and copy the binaries + other files needed (before this, I naturally install the core episerver installation on the target server). Then it's just a little IIS configuration and things are working.

Future updates after that involves deploying from visual studio and export / import new/change pagetypes, etc.